# When to combine multi-related/join tables

Tags: sql-server

Considering database performance, please review this example..

If there are only 50,000 widgets in table one,two and three (total) and 50,000,000 widgets in table four.

Using the following relational/join table to handle the first three relationships:

```
    ID (int)
    IndexID (int)
    RelationType (int)
    RelationID (int)
```

Would it be ok just to use this relational table for table four as well (by changing the relationtype to Table4), but considering it has a signifigantly larger amount of data than the first three tables?  Or should table four have its own relational/join table:

```
   ID (int)
   IndexID (int)
   RelationID (int)
```

Comment: I would give it its own relationship with the first join table, else if you'd want to query something for which you only need the first 3 tables you'd have to go through a LOT more records.

Comment: So out of the 2 examples, you would go with the second one for the fourth table in the example?

Comment: Why do you have the widgets scattered over four tables?

Comment: yes I'd go for the second one (however I'm just a 3d year student computer science so just expressing my opinion here, maybe a backend programming specialist would say something else)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same relational table for table4 too and create a non clustered index on relationId.

Performance in inserting might be little slow but traversal and relating will be done fast.